# If $S, T$ are subsets of a vector space, is $[S ∩ T ] = [S] ∩ [T ]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can someone help me visualize what is going on here? What is the difference between $[S ∩ T ]$ and $[S] ∩ [T]$?

Comment: What do the brackets stand for here?

Comment: Probably the brackets denote linear span.

Comment: they indicate span

Answer (score 1):

On one hand: $$S \cap T \subseteq S \subseteq [S] \implies [S \cap T]\subseteq [S],$$and similarly $[S\cap T]\subseteq[T]$, hence $[S \cap T]\subseteq [S]\cap [T]$. In words: the linear span of the intersection of two sets is contained in the intersection of the linear span of the two sets.

The other inclusion is, in general, false. Take for example in $\Bbb R^2$: $$S = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}, \quad T = \{(1,1)\},$$so that: $$[S \cap T] = \{0\} \supsetneq [S]\cap [T] = \Bbb R^2 \cap \Bbb R(1,1) = \Bbb R(1,1).$$

---

**Obs.:** I use $\Bbb R(1,1)$ as the set $\{\lambda(1,1) \mid \lambda \in \Bbb R\}$, that is, the line passing through the origin with direction $(1,1)$.

Comment: how did you get [S∩T]=0?? How do you find the intersection of the two subspaces.  Also, does "S={(1,0),(0,1)}" mean that S spans the x and y axes?

Comment: Well, in my example $S \cap T = \{0\}$, so $[S \cap T] = [\{0\}] = \{0\}$. Note that $S$ and $T$ don't have to be subspaces, only *subsets*, so I just took a set with two elements, and another set with only one element.

Comment: Yes, $S$ *spans* both axes. We write that as $[S] = \Bbb R^2$. But the set $S$ only has two vectors.

Comment: how does S∩T={0}? Not sure why I'm not seeing it

Comment: So then T spans both axes too right? But only has one vector

Comment: Is $(1,1)$ in $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$? Pay attention to the diference between $[$ and $]$ to $\{$ and $\}$.

Comment: No. $T$ only spans a line.

Comment: Actually, $S\cap T=\varnothing$ in that example, not $\{0\}$.

Comment: Ah. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: But by convention $[\varnothing] = \{0\}$, so there's no harm done.

Comment: @Jackie let's go through it step by step: the subset $S$ consists only of two vectors, which span the whole $\Bbb R^2$. The set $T$ consists only of one vector, which spans a line. Their intersection is the empty set, which spans the null space $\{0\}$. My mistake in saying $S \cap T = \{0\}$ was because I already was thinking of spans, in other words, I thought way ahead of myself (try to learn something from my mistake here). If you still have any questions, I'll do my best to answer them (and not screw up again)

Comment: What is that zero symbol with the line through it?  Also can you write in words what this means: "[S∩T]= [S]∩[T]" Like i can't intuitively understand the difference between the span the brackets with both sets inside and separate brackets

Comment: The symbol $\varnothing$ stands for the empty set: a set which has **no** elements. The whole discussion resumes to $[S \cap T]\color{red}{\neq} [S]\cap[T]$, only one inclusion is true.

Comment: How did you find that their intersection was the empty set?

Comment: Because the sets $\{(1,1)\}$ and $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ have no elements in common.

Comment: But (1,0) + (0,1)=(1,1) doesn't that show that T is in the span of S?

Comment: Yes! You're right. But you're saying that $T \subseteq [S]$, **not** $T \subseteq S$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $ [] $ meaning $ span $ the statement is false:
Let $ S $ be $ \{(1,0)\} $ and let $ T $ be $ \{(2,0)\} $
$ [S \cap T] = span(S \cap T) = \emptyset $
while $ [S] \cap [T] = span(S) \cap span(T) = span(S) = span(T) = span\{(1,0)\} = span\{(2,0)\} $